# Displacement making spikes

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials, node-editor, displacement

I was following an old CG geek tutorial and i randomly got a crap ton of spikes that just appeared out of nowhere when I switched it from "Displacement only" to "Displacement and Bump". I can't get it back either, the spikes stay there, please help.

https://youtu.be/iRbERWmJhmk
- This is the problem

Comment: could you please share the file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: oh i restarted the project and just re entered most of the nodes, seemed to work.  I probably checked some setting.